# Extend a returned Instance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instance

I'm a Java newbie and ran into a bit of a problem. I want a class to become another class. It's hard to explain it the abstract way, so I'll give you an example.

```
public class WorldGuard extends WorldGuardPlugin {
    public WorldGuard(Plugin parent) {
        WorldGuardPlugin plugin = parent.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldGuard")
        // make plugin the actual class
    }
}
```

`WorldGuard` should act like some kind of a wrapper here. When constructed it gets one parameter `parent` on which base it finds an instance of `WorldGuardPlugin`. The class should now *become* that instance.
It's simple in JavaScript, I just return the instance, but I can't do this in Java.

Comment: Oh look, its a bukkit plugin question.  Have you asked in #bukkitdev on irc.esper.net?  That said, your question makes very little sense and I can't get anything out of it.  Try looking at existing plugins.

Comment: You can't change the class of an object. All you can do is wrap the object or create a new object with another class.

Comment: That wrapping behaviour would so the trick. But how do I tell the class to delegate all calls to another class?

Comment: When you extend a class, the super class will automatically handle all calls to methods defined in the super class unless you explicitly override them in your subclass.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I explicitly point to the already existing instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. A class cannot "become another class". But perhaps your problem is just that you're trying to use a constructor when you should be using a plain function. Maybe what you want to do is this:

```
public class WorldGuard extends WorldGuardPlugin
{
  public static WorldGuard getFromPlugin(Plugin parent)
  {
    return (WorldGuard) parent.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldGuard");
  }
}
```

That would get the object via parent and return it as a WorldGuard object.

Comment: I knew that I'd have to do that kinda ugly extra function. I just wanted the whole class to act like this single function, because creating a new class just for getting a reference seems abit overhead to me...

Comment: You don't have to create a new class. I presume you need the WorldGuard class anyway. Just put the static function into the WorldGuard class.

Answer (score 1):

Class cannot become other class.

I think you can choose among the following possibilities.

1. User Factory that creates instance of your classes. The factory will choose concrete class according to any logic you want and create instance of "right" class. If you want all classes the factory operates with can implement specific interface, so caller will not even know instance of which class is created.
2. Use wrapper pattern. In this case your actual `WordGuard` class will wrap actual instance of other class and delegate all calls there.
3. Use dynamic proxy or byte code engineering solution. But it is much more complicated and is not the best solution in most cases.

Comment: 2) seems promising. Is there a way to just say "delegate all calls to that class"?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the copy constructor of `WorldGuardPlugin`. What I mean is that `WorldGuardPlugin` should have a constructor that can create a copy of a given instance of the class like:

```
WorldGuardPlugin pg = new WorldGuardPlugin(anInstance);
```

If this is the case then you are in luck. You can simply do:

```
public class WorldGuard extends WorldGuardPlugin {
    public WorldGuard(Plugin parent) {
        super( parent.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldGuard"));
    }
}
```

This will make "WorldGuard act like some kind of a wrapper here". You can still call the methods defined in `WorldGuardPlugin` on an instance of `WorldGuard` while being able to add methods to `WorldGuard` itself.

Comment: Sadly `WorldGuardPlugin` doesn't offer that copy constructor.

Comment: Or instead is there a parameterized constructor, that you could use to initialize members yourself?

Comment: The constructor doesn't take any parameters. This approach doesn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of object being constructed in a constructor. A constructor, by definition, constructs that class (e.g. `A`'s constructor creates a type `A`).

In your example, `WorldGuard` extends `WorldGuardPlugin`, which means that `WorldGuard` *is* a type of `WorldGuardPlugin`. Maybe there is a way to initialize the `WorldGuardPluin` class (using a call to `super` in the constructor) with the properties that you want.